# How do I use 'model builder' in QGIS 2.2?

Tags: qgis, modelbuilder, qgis-processing

I am trying to learn how to use the 'model builder' in QGIS 2.2. I have used model builder in ArcGIS, but I don't understand how to do it in QGIS 2.2?

What I want to do is to make buffers, clip vector layers and, if it's possible, add columns and data to attribute tables?

I want to do the same process for quite a few different layers, so it would be nice to get help from a model.

Is there any instructive tutorials to be found online that can show me how to make a model?
I tried to google it, but didn't find what I needed.

Comment: SoS, if you have tried other tutorial sources and they are insufficient, indicate **why** and what you have tried already! Otherwise it does appear to be a duplicate, given the answers in the link @PolyGeo has shown.

Comment: The question about how to add row numbers to a layer using Processing should be a new thread. Please accept the answer on your original question and create a new thread for your follow-up questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was starting to work with it a week ago and it's a little bit strange from the arc-user-perspective. You have to start with adding your input data for example with double-click on "vector layer". This is just an empty slot while you are creating the model. Afterwards you can add the functions. At the last function you give a name for the output. Everything without a name will be just temporary data. IMPORTAND: The function didn’t work or change if you don’t save it!
Here is a nice introduction: http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/processing/modeler.html
The rest is learning by doing. Have fun and good luck!

Comment: Here's an updated link since the one above no longer works: http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/processing/modeler.html

Comment: Update 2018 https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/processing/modeler.html